# access name and marks using c# lambda expression from webservice response

Tags: c#, linq, web-services

access name and marks using c# lambda expression from webservice response

I have a webservice, which return the response in below format.

```
  <StudentList>
   <Infromation>
    <RelatedDetails>
      <Student>
        <Details>
          <name></name>
          <marks></marks>
        </Details>
      </Student>
    </RelatedDetails>
  </Information>
</StudentList>
```

I have already consumed my webservice and want to read response.
I have prepared model as StudentDetails with properties Name and Marks.

```
class StudentDetails
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public decimal Marks{get;set;}
}
```

So I want to read name and marks from above response (using some lambda expression or some easy way)

Need help in getting result from response something as below...

```
response.student(x => x. ////something to be here)
```

Please suggest.

Comment: have you already deserialized the xml to collection of students?

Comment: Yes Sajid. Deserilized and it's available in response (students)

Comment: can you add to the question the class and the sample of the collection. or you can do the code like : `List<StudentDetails> studentDetails = studentlist.Select(s=>new StudentDetails {name = s.Information.Name, marks =s.Information.marks}).ToList();`

Comment: Hi Sajid, here information is a list. meaning, we can have multiple information tags in response. so s.information ===> its a list to be filtered with name. How to achieve this.

Comment: without updating the question with class structure, i can't give good answer :) but if *information* is list too, you could use `SelectMany` to flatten list of list to one list:`List<StudentDetails> studentDetails = studentlist.SelectMany(s => s.Information).Select(i => new StudentDetails {name = i.Name, marks =i.marks}).ToList();`

Comment: Hi Sajid, I have edited my question with correct response from webservice, could you please help to get name and marks please.